# Intersecting RegionPlots

Tags: plotting, graphics, computational-geometry, regions, intersection

Does the Mathematica graphics system have any concept of intersecting regionplots? I've found about intersecting graphics but not regionplots so far. For example, if I want to show the intersection of these 2 regionplots:

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
RegionPlot[x < 0.5, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

I know I can use Opacity and place both regionplots on top of each other using:

```
PLOT1 = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Opacity[0.2]}, BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Thick]]
PLOT2 = RegionPlot[x < 0.5, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},PlotStyle -> {Red, Opacity[0.05]}, BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red]]
Show[PLOT1, PLOT2, LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20]]
```

[image]

Or more simply:

```
RegionPlot[{x^2 + y^3 < 2, x < 0.5}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},PlotLegends->{"PLOT1", "PLOT2"}]
```

[image]
However the common regions become less visible the more regionplots I want to intersect. I would like to exclude everything that is not part of the intersection and obtain this:

[image]

I know that I could write:

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2 && x < 0.5, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

OR

```
A = x^2 + y^3 < 2
B = x < 0.5;
RegionPlot[And[A, B], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

But if A and B are heavier expressions, or that I want to find the intersection of more than 2 regionplots, the calculations can become too heavy.

Is there a way, in my example, to draw separately RegionPlot1 and RegionPlot2 (the way I started with Opacity) and then get a unique RegionPlot but showing only the region where the 2 regionplots intersect (I wish there was a function 'RegionPlotIntersection[PLOT1,PLOT2]')?

Thanks a lot in advance.

So thank you so much for your comments! These functions were not on Mathematica 9 so I got Mathematica 10. Indeed, I get the graphic of the intersection using ImplicitRegion, RegionIntersection and BoundaryDiscretizedRegion!

```
PLOT1 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}];
PLOT2 = ImplicitRegion[x < 0.5, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}];
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[PLOT1,PLOT2]]
```

OR, what can be better sharing the weight of calculations among the 3 steps:

```
PLOT1=BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}]];
PLOT2=BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[x < 0.5, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}]];
RegionIntersection[PLOT1,PLOT2]
```

[image]

And pretty neat, it works with more than 2 regionplots!

```
PLOT1 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}];
PLOT2 = ImplicitRegion[x < 0.5, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}];
PLOT3 = ImplicitRegion[y > 0, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}];
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[PLOT1,PLOT2,PLOT3]]
```

[image]

NEW ADDITIONAL QUESTION: I get a naked graphic and I can't find the equivalent of 'AxesLabel' for discretized graphic, is there a way to keep the axes and values?

Answer: I didn't find something working including DiscretizeRegion and FrameLabel, but I keep the frame if I use RegionPlot instead:

```
PLOT1 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}];
PLOT2 = ImplicitRegion[x < 0.5, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}];
RegionPlot[RegionIntersection[PLOT1,PLOT2],PlotRange->{{-2,2},{-2,2}}]
PLOT3 = ImplicitRegion[y > 0, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}];
RegionPlot[RegionIntersection[PLOT1,PLOT2,PLOT3],PlotRange->{{-2,2},{-2,2}}]
```

[image]
[image]

My only concern is that I'm not entirely sure that I'm splitting the calculations for Mathematica. In terms on weight of calculations, I'm wondering whether it's not the same as writing:

```
PLOT = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^3 < 2 && x < 0.5 && y > 0, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}];
```

Comment: Probably it could help to share the code that define your regions so we can experience the problem. Would `Reduce[And[A, B]]` help? Did you try `DiscretizeRegion`?

Comment: Could you use a combination of `RegionIntersection` and `ImplicitRegion`s?

Comment: Look up `Frame` and `FrameLabel`.

Comment: `RegionPlot` can handle more than one region: `RegionPlot[{x < 0.5, x^2 + y^3 < 2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]`

Comment: Thank you, it's actually a better way than with Opacity but my question here was to keep only the intersecting region(s).

Comment: Did you not try adding the option `Frame -> True` to your plots?

Comment: Yes but I couldn't find a way to "Frame->True" to "DiscretizeRegion"! can you?

Comment: Elsa, I don't understand: just like @J.M. suggested, the `Frame` and `Axes` options work just fine with `DiscretizeRegion` ([examples](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ae9XP.png)). For now I am voting to close this question as it may stem from a syntactic misunderstanding.

Comment: I would suggest that your solution should be posted as an answer.  And the "NEW ADDITIONAL QUESTION" should be asked as a new question.